# What technology is the HTTP and UI level of application based on EJB architecture?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, ejb, ejb-3.1

I read a lot about possible Java Web Development architectures (servlets+JSP, Spring MVC, Struts etc.). One of them is "plain Java EE 6" with EJB 3, in opposition to Spring/Spring MVC.

I started to read book (EJB 3.1) and tutorials, but I can't find single example of where the request to EJB starts at "human level" or what is the complete (with UI) architecture.

What is the most popular technology that connects Enterprise Java Beans bussines functionality at HTTP and web browser level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) (JavaServer Faces) is a technology formalized as part of Java Enterprise Edition. JSF 2.0 was released together with Java EE 6.

Comment: And is it the most popular combination (JSF(facelets) + EJB) in real word projects?

Comment: @hbpitero: that I haven't said. You are free to use any framework you want, I like Spring MVC, Wicket. Play is gaining a lot of momentum. But JSF is *the* standard.

Comment: I mean combination with EJB. Is connecting spring MVC with EJB popular?

Comment: @hbpitero: I never worked on pure EJB project. If you are using Spring MVC, Spring framework might be more obvious choice. But it's possible. As a matter of fact you can integrate virtually any web framework with EJB. There are no specifically popular ones.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz You can use virtually any framework with EJB indeed, but the model of JSF having backing beans that are injected with services (EJB beans) is specifically tailored to work together. Just as a couple of other parts from Java EE, like JPA and Bean Validation can all be used with any mix and match of styles, frameworks and patterns you can think of, they particularly (or perhaps "at least" is a better word) work well together.

Comment: I'm working on a project with `PURE Java EE` and `PURE Java EE` only. `(JPA + EJB) -> (JSF/JAX-RS/JAX-WS)` is the way to go.